# Running parallelism for multiple optional stages

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing

I am using the Jenkins declarative pipeline and am currently attempting to parallelize part of my workflow. The way my pipeline currently works is that there are multiple stages for building a database, each with when clauses dependent upon parameters passed to the build. Following that there are multiple stages for building an application, which also have when clauses based on params. I'm trying to put both these chains of stages into parallel but can't figure out if it's possible with the declarative syntax as I would either have to put all the stages into parallel, which is a no go because later stages relating to each task rely on the earlier ones, or nest these stages into some parent stages which doesnt seem to be supported by the declarative syntax. I would like to perform something like this. Any information that could help would be appreciated.

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage("Build Systems"){
            parallel{
                stage("Build Database"){
                        stage("DB STEP 1"){
                            steps{
                                echo 'building databse step 1'
                            }
                        }
                        stage("DB STEP 2"){
                            steps{
                                echo 'building databse step 2'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("Build Application"){
                        stage("APP STEP 1"){
                            steps{
                                echo 'building application step 1'
                            }
                        }
                        stage("APP STEP 2"){
                            steps{
                                echo 'building application step 2'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Four stage here for DB Step1, DB Step2, App Step1, App Step2. Which you want to parallel, which you want to be sequence, please make your question clear.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this just got implemented with [Declarative Pipeline 1.3: **Sequential Stages**](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/07/02/whats-new-declarative-piepline-13x-sequential-stages/).

> One common use case is running build and tests on multiple platforms.
>   You could already do that with parallel stages, but **now you can run multiple stages in each parallel branch giving you more visibility into the progress of your Pipeline without having to check the logs to see exactly which step is currently running where**, etc.

[image: https://jenkins.io/images/post-images/2018-07-02/sequential_stages.png]